# How do I get my Selenium Grid Hub log

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-grid, selenium-grid2

I have a selenium grid2 set up on an AWS instance, and I was wondering if there's a way I could view the logs on my local machine?

I understand I can visit: http://MyServerAddress/grid/console and view all of the nodes but I want the actual log.
Its a bit of a pain having to remote desktop to the server each time I want to view it.

I was thinking something like http://MyServerAddress/grid/log but alas, it doesnt seem to be an option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's nothing available out of the box. But you can build this on your own.

- You would first need to enable logging for your Grid and have the logs dumped to a specific folder.
- You would now need to build a custom Servlet and inject it into the servlet (See [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp#customizing-the-grid) for details on how to do it )
- Assuming that your servlet is called "HubLogServlet", you should be able to access it via the link http://localhost:4444/grid/admin/HubLogServlet

You can refer to this [LogServlet](https://github.com/paypal/SeLion/blob/develop/server/src/main/java/com/paypal/selion/node/servlets/LogServlet.java) for a sample.

Comment: This answers my question. Thanks for this.